# Batch process for displaying date & name stamp on photos

Tags: photo-editing, batch

I could not find a dedicated photo-editing section, hence posting here. Apologies if wrong place.

**Query:**

I have thousands of photos, which I need to show time/date/custom-text on all photos.

Editing all individuals photos will be impossible!

Is there any way to do this in **batch-mode**?

Comment: See also [How to watermark a folder of photographs?](/questions/10013/how-to-watermark-a-folder-of-photographs)

Comment: See also [How do you create a watermark for photos?](/questions/3271/how-do-you-create-a-watermark-for-photos)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to add text to photos, either overlaid on the photo or on a border. See the [annotation section](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#annotating) of the documentation for a number of examples. Because ImageMagick is a set of command line tools, you can easily incorporate it into batch processes using shell scripts and other scripting tools.

**Example:** I've got a photo of some flowers, and I want to add the file name in white text in the lower left corner of the image. Here's the photo:

[image: flowers.jpg]

I can use ImageMagick's `convert` command to generate a new file that shows the file name. (The command takes a number of parameters, so I'm going to break the line with backslashes, but you can enter it all on one line if you want.)

```
$ convert flowers.jpg -font CourierNewB -pointsize 14 \
      -draw "gravity southwest fill white text 12,12 'flowers.jpg'" \
      flowers_title.jpg
```

The result is a new file names `flowers_title.jpg`:

[image: flowers_title.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with free [Faststone Image Viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm).

Select images, then go to Tools -> Batch Convert Selected Images, then click in Advanced Options and in tab Watermark or Text select the text you want to place on your photos (data from exif and/or your own text).